# Is there any alternative to UpgradeAdapter.registerForNg1Tests?

Tags: angularjs, angular, ng-upgrade, angular-upgrade

I have an Angular hybrid app which use `UpgradeModule`. The AngularJS components depend on Angular services downgraded by `downgradeInjectable`. When I unit test the components, I saw this error.

> Error: Error while instantiating injectable 'MyService': Not a valid '@angular/upgrade' application.
>
> Did you forget to downgrade an Angular module or include it in the AngularJS application?

I found [`UpgradeAdapter.registerForNg1Tests`](https://angular.io/api/upgrade/UpgradeAdapter#registerforng1tests) and it solved this error. I love this function but the module `UpgradeAdapter` is said *deprecated*. I would like to use some alternative function which is not deprecated if exists.

Comment: Could you share a code example of how you fixed this? Would help out a lot.